# Find elements which sum is closest to a given value

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have searched and read about algorithms for this problem but they don't seem to apply in this case, or were not clear enough.

I have a `List<decimal>` of **unsigned** values where I'm trying to find the element(s) which **sum is the closest to a specified value N**

The List is of variable size with average of 500 elements. **Performance is NOT a priority** for this solution.

The implemented method should return a **single solution** or an empty list if no solution is found.

Existing more than one, pick one with the less elements.

```
Example:

N = 15.00

Elements = {
0.10, //EDIT: This shouldn't be here
7.00,
7.00,
14.10,
15.90,
}

Solutions = {
0.10 + 7.00 + 7.00, //EDIT: This shouldn't be here
14.10,
15.90,
} 

Final Solution = {14.10} // or 15.90
```

Comment: This needs more clarification.  What are the possible solutions for an answer?  Any combination of any of the numbers in Element?  If so, your final solution doesn't make sense because 14.10 + 0.10 would be 14.20, which is closer to 15 than 14.10 is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `{14.10 + 0.10}` is better than your proposed "correct" answer.  Anyway dynamic programming gets this done very efficiently.  Pruned dynamic programming, even moreso.

Comment: This is very closely related to the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem), and the same approach will work (with a small modification to change the hard limit to a soft limit)

Comment: Branch and bound solution could be effective, but any exact solution will be O(2^n) due to the fact that this is effectively subset sum.

Comment: I hope this stays open, I'd like to see a `C#` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

First, add this handy Combination extension: ([credits to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1898744/4905310))

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
    {
        return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
          elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
            elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
    }
}
```

And then:

```
private IEnumerable<decimal> ClosestSum(decimal[] elements, decimal n)
{
    var target = Enumerable.Range(1, elements.Length)
        .SelectMany(p => elements.Combinations(p))
        .OrderBy(p => Math.Abs((decimal)p.Sum() - n))
        .ThenBy(p => p.Count())
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return target ?? new decimal[] { };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in time linear with respect to the input with a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach.

```
    private class Solution
    {
        public int StartIndex;
        public int EndIndex;
        public decimal Sum;
        public int Length
        {
            get { return EndIndex - StartIndex + 1; }
        }

    }

    static List<decimal> Solve(List<decimal> elements, decimal target)
    {
        Solution bestSolution = new Solution { StartIndex = 0, EndIndex = -1, Sum = 0 };
        decimal bestError = Math.Abs(target);
        Solution currentSolution = new Solution { StartIndex = 0, Sum = 0 };

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
        {
            currentSolution.EndIndex = i;
            currentSolution.Sum += elements[i];
            while (elements[currentSolution.StartIndex] <= currentSolution.Sum - target)
            {
                currentSolution.Sum -= elements[currentSolution.StartIndex];
                ++currentSolution.StartIndex;
            }
            decimal currentError = Math.Abs(currentSolution.Sum - target);
            if (currentError < bestError || currentError == bestError && currentSolution.Length < bestSolution.Length )
            {
                bestError = currentError;
                bestSolution.Sum = currentSolution.Sum;
                bestSolution.StartIndex = currentSolution.StartIndex;
                bestSolution.EndIndex = currentSolution.EndIndex;
            }
        }

        return elements.GetRange(bestSolution.StartIndex, bestSolution.Length);
    }
```

Comment: "in linear time"... linear in *what*?  Not in the number of elements in the input set.

Comment: The memory requirement isn't O(1) either, since you have to store a list.

Comment: In fact, the only part of your answer that's right are the words "dynamic programming".  Ohhh, I see, you're assuming runs of adjacent elements.  I can't tell whether the problem actually is restricted to adjacent runs or not.

Comment: replaced rough draft proof with code, if shardl wants subsequence then @Gabriel has the correct answer

Comment: I've tested this and it seems to work, but just looking at the code I can't determine if this returns the solution with least elements.

Comment: But what if have array [10,1,30,40,50] and the number i want to find is 4? the closest should be 1 ? but it resturn empty result. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I typed in some old-fashioned way, but works perfectly!

```
    bool InRange(decimal num, decimal value, decimal range)
    {
        return ((num >= value - range) && (num < value + range));
    }

    decimal GetClosestSum(decimal value, List<decimal> elements, decimal range)
    {
        elements.Sort();
        var possibleResults = new List<decimal>();
        for (int x = elements.Count - 1; x > 0; x--)
        {
            if (InRange(elements[x], value, range)) possibleResults.Add(elements[x]);
            decimal possibleResult = elements[x];
            for (int i = x - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                possibleResult += elements[i];
                if (possibleResult > (value + range - 1)) possibleResult -= elements[i];
                if (InRange(possibleResult, value, range)) possibleResults.Add(possibleResult);
            }
        }
        decimal bestResult = -1;
        for (int x = 0; x < possibleResults.Count; x++)
        {
            if (bestResult == -1)
                bestResult = possibleResults[x];
            if (Math.Abs(value - possibleResults[x]) < Math.Abs(value - bestResult))
                bestResult = possibleResults[x];
        }
        return bestResult;
    }
```